# alternative of Orientdb getVertexByKey() deprecated method in 2.2.10?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I am using **Orientdb 2.2.10**

**What I want?**

I want to **get a vertex** having **uId** = 'ram' of **classtype** = "Person" from my Graphdb.

My **graphdb is indexed with unique key 'uid'.**

**How I am solving it?**

- I am using this function to get the vertex : **graph.getVertexByKey(key)**;
- I am **getting the desire result** but my IDE(eclipse) showing it as **deprecated method**

Is there any alternative of this in 2.2.10?

If not, is it safe to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Iterable<Vertex> it=g.getVertices("uid", "ram");
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for answering..!

Comment: any method which returns Vertex directly instead of Iterable?